# How to Optimize big Data Tables VueJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, babel-loader

I have this table that I'm using to intelligently render over 4000 records, but I want to know how to do it in a way that there is no lag whatsoever. I did a performance recording using so I could see how the memory was being used and I ended up with this.[image]

This is actually much more optimized than what I had before and I'm achieving this by conditionally rendering all but the first td in each row in order to maintain height for scrolling, but also to reduce the amount of nodes that are being iterated over. Is there any way that I can optimize this further?

Here is my Vue Template

```
<template>
<div class="table-container" >
    <div class="table-header" ref="tableHead">
        <table class="data-table" border="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th
                        v-for="(head, index) in contents.order"
                        :key="index"
                        class="col"
                        :class="contents.stickyCols.indexOf(head) === 0 ? 'sticky-left' : contents.stickyCols.indexOf(head) === 1 ? 'sticky-right' : ''"> {{ head }}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="table-body" ref="tableBody" @scroll="changeScrollVal" :style="'height: ' + height + ';'">
        <table id="bodytable" width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <tbody>
                <tr
                    v-for="(row, idx) in theData"
                    :key="idx">
                    <td
                        :class="contents.stickyCols.indexOf(key) === 0 ? 'sticky-left' : contents.stickyCols.indexOf(key) === 1 ? 'sticky-right' : ''"
                        :style="contents.colorCols.indexOf(key) > -1 ? 'color:' + contents.colorRefs[row[contents.colorRefs.label]] : '' "
                        class="body-cell col"
                        v-for="(key, index) in contents.order"
                        v-if="idx >= (scrollBottom / 6 - 100 < 0 ? 0 : scrollBottom / 6 - 100) && idx <= scrollBottom - 1 || key === contents.order[0]"
                        :key="index"
                        >{{ row[key] }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
                                       <!-- > {{ row[key] }} -->                   
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
props: ['contents', 'dashData', 'height'],
data () {
    return {
        theData: [],
        scrollBottom: 100
    }
},
methods: {
    changeScrollVal (e) {
        this.$refs.tableHead.scrollLeft = e.target.scrollLeft
        this.scrollBottom = Math.floor(this.$refs.tableBody.scrollTop / 9 < 100 ? 100 : this.$refs.tableBody.scrollTop / 9 > this.dashData.length - 1 ? this.dashData.length - 1 : this.$refs.tableBody.scrollTop / 9)
        this.theData = this.dashData.slice(0, this.scrollBottom)
    }
},
mounted () {
    this.theData = this.dashData// .slice(0, 17)
}
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
table
{
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.sticky-right {
position: sticky;
background: white;
right: 0;
padding-left: 20px!important;
}

.sticky-left {
position: sticky;
background: white;
left: 0;
}

.outer-container
{
background-color: #ccc;
position: absolute;
top:0;
left: 0;
right: 300px;
bottom: 40px;
}

.inner-container
{
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.table-header
{
position: relative;
&::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
}
.table-body
{
overflow: scroll;
display:inline-block;
width: 79vw;
}

.table-header {
overflow: scroll;
width: 79vw;
}

th
{
background-color: white;
text-align: left;
height: 40px;
}
.body-cell 
{
text-align: left;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.col
{
width:120px;
min-width: 265px;
max-width: 265px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
font-weight: 500;
// background-color: white;
}
</style>
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1) can you provide a small data sample
2) do you need data to re-render (I'm thinking v-once)

Comment: Sorry I can't. It's proprietary data

Comment: ... just the structure, not real data  :)

Comment: If you just give it the order props with your own dataset it should work. contents.order is an array of column names that references the keys in your dataset json. also you will want to pass give it this `contents : { order: ['your', 'order'], colorCols: [], stickyCols[]}` Then pass your data as  the `dashData` prop

Comment: According to the official vue style guide, using v-for together with v-if can lead to lowered efficiency: [Avoid v-if with v-for](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential)

Comment: I made some test and the problem is as always the DOM. I think you should consider creating a "Virtual Table" (only render the rows in view). Maybe have a look at  https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller

Comment: using **pagination** in client, then if possible, optimize backbend to support get data with parameters like `{'pageNum':1, 'pageCount':20, ...}, normally it doesn't need to load full data.

Comment: I don't want to use pagination. It's ugly, difficult to maintain, and takes away from User Experience. @Jakob, I am actually doing that in my script. I did manage to add filters and a search feature that reduces the amount of DOM nodes dramatically. I think I'll just have to settle for a slightly laggy solution. My only other option would be to take screenshots of arrays of `tr` elements as the user scrolls and then replacing them dynamically. The only problem with that is that I have to redo it each time the user filters the data. We'll see what happens.